# See when sidekiq job was queued [from inside the job]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have an async sidekiq job in rails [one of many] that I would like to expire if it has not completed within a few minutes. I found a pretty simple solution in just sending the `Time.now.to_s` as a parameter to the job, but I'd prefer to keep that logic in the job itself. So far i've found nothing using ApplicationJob/ActiveJob (eg setting the job in `before_perform` or Sidekiq::Worker. Should I just stick with my naive solution? I'm currently calling the job using `.delay`

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq stores the `enqueued_at` attribute in the job payload but does not expose it to the Worker.  It is visible to the middleware layer and to the API.